# mysql statement for adding multiple columns whether they exist or not

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, alter

I'm trying to write an update mysql statement for a software program. Currently this is what I have for the statment, but I don't now how to add multiple columns to update.

This code currently adds the column whether it's there or not.

---

```
/*delimiter '//'
CREATE PROCEDURE addcol() BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME=`top_status` AND TABLE_NAME='categories'
)
THEN
ALTER TABLE `categories`
ADD COLUMN `top_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1';
END IF;
END;
delimiter ';'
CALL addcol();
DROP PROCEDURE addcol;*/
```

---

Can someone supply me with the correct statement to get something like this to work...ie. WHERE COLUMN_NAME = column1, column2 etc..

I've tried all kinds of variations and all of them return an error in phpmyadmin except the above.

Answer (score 6):

Use ALTER TABLE statement to add multiple columns to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD (column1 col_definition,
column2 col_definition,
column3 col_definition,
....      ......
....      ......
columnN col_definition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want to individually test for the existence of the new columns, and add each one individually if it doesn't already exist?

If you want the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` query to test for the existence of **any** of the columns column1, column2 etc. you can use an `IN` statement. If you want to test whether they **all** exist then you can use `IN` and instead of checking whether the resultset is empty, select a `COUNT(*)` and check whether the count returned is the expected number (the number of columns involved).

Comment: is my method even the correct way to do this?  What I'm trying to do is setup a statement I can use for many different databases that are outdated at different version with different data/columns.  Some db's have the columns, some don't, some have all the latest columns.  But I just want one statement to run against each db to basically make all db's the same and latest build.  So, is this the best method or is there a better way?  Also, is below post the way you would go about adding your statements?

Comment: /*delimiter '//'
    CREATE PROCEDURE addcol() BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (`top_status, 'categories') AND       TABLE_NAME='categories'
)
    THEN
    ALTER TABLE `categories`
    ADD COLUMN (`top_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default     '1',`categories` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1');
    END IF;
    END;
    delimiter ';'
    CALL addcol();
    DROP PROCEDURE addcol;*/

This doesn't work btw.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for `ALTER TABLE`; the correct syntax is `ALTER TABLE categories ADD COLUMN top_status tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1', ADD COLUMN categories tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1'`

Comment: The `IF` statement in your comment tests whether the table has at least one of the columns `top_status` and `categories`. If it has one, but not the other, then the `IF` statement is satisfied and you will run into an error when you attempt to add the column that is already present. So, if the table might have some columns but not others, you need to test for the presence of each column individually and deal with each one that isn't there. This means multiple `IF` statements.

Comment: ok, this is what I have now and it's still not updating both columns.  No errors, but no adding either. /*delimiter '//'
    CREATE PROCEDURE addcol() BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (`categories_status, `top_status') AND  TABLE_NAME='categories'
)
    THEN
    ALTER TABLE `categories`
    ADD COLUMN `categories_status` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',`top_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1';
    END IF;
    END;
    delimiter ';'
    CALL addcol();
    DROP PROCEDURE addcol;*/

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` statement you posted there is not the statement I posted above. As far as I can tell, the syntax of your statement is not correct (per MySQL's documentation for `ALTER TABLE`). I would expect an error message. I cannot explain why it runs without errors and does nothing.

Comment: Well, I don't then.  it's over my head.  If i do multiple if statements I get procedure dupe.  Basically no matter what I do I either get errors with no columns added, or I don't get errors with no columns added.  Also, this site is hard to post code, I keep messing it up on here.